# How to can add symbols between words?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a way to add automatically different symbols such as _ or spaces between words but in random order and not to be depend on the word's length

```
my_str = "Good morning everyone"

# replace space with underscore
str = my_str.replace(" ", '_')

# print the output
print(str)
```

How can the the words be displayed as "Good_Morning_Everyone"

Comment: Please tag with the language being used. `underscore.js` is a specific library for a specific language that the snippet isn't.

Comment: The code isn't javascript. It looks like python.

Answer (score 0):

You should use regular expressions.

You could, for instance, do the following instruction:

```
my_str = "Good morning everyone";
console.log(my_str.replace(/ /g, "_"));
```

Comment: can you please explain it a little bit?

Comment: Yeah no problem. Regular expressions, often called regexp, are string-like objects used to find character patterns in a text. Here the regexp is `/ /g`. You could also have declared it with the syntax `new Regexp(' ','g')`. The **g** -for **global**- is used to state that you would like to search all occurences of the string. The string here is simply composed of a space character. If you want further details on how to use regular expressions please visit [Mozilla's documentation on RegExp for JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: Consider adding your explanation (or a version of it) to the answer itself. Comments are "second class citizens" and are sometimes removed.

Comment: This doesn't really address the part of the question regarding replacing with random characters. OP is already using regex.